# NodeJS - my app is not able to start

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to bring up my NodeJS app which runs perfectly on a different Windows box, but I get the below error on Win 7 box:

```
C:\aaaa\at>c:\nodejs\npm start

> application-name@0.0.1 start C:\aaaa\at
> node ./bin/www


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (C:\aaaa\at\node_modules\socket.io\lib\in
dex.js:214:9)
    at new Server (C:\aaaa\at\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:51:17)
    at Server (C:\aaaa\at\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:39:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\aaaa\at\app.js:7:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "c:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "c:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd aaaa\at
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\aaaa\at\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

As per the above error:

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\aaaa\at\app.js:7:37)
```

This is the loc:

```
global.socket = require('socket.io')(80, {'transports': ['polling']});
```

I am not sure how to resolve this one?

Comment: Maybe there's another server running on the specified port (like IIS)? Or you need to use elevated permissions (ie administrator privilege) to bind to the port, try running the command shell as administrator.

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue, yes the port was being used by some other app

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then since answering in comments is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely another server running on that port (maybe Internet Information Server since you're on Windows). Try stopping that, or change the port that node runs on.